# Qt, communication between classes

Tags: c++, qt

I have two classes `MainWindow` and `Worker`. `MainWindow` is basically responsible for GUI and the worker is for connecting with the server. `MainWindow` has an instance of `Worker`. If `Worker` receives a message from the server it is supposed to change the GUI, but I can not find a way to communicate them. I thought about making MainWindow a singleton, and then use slots and signals. But maybe is there an easier way, like some function to get the object of the current View?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mentioned signals/slots in your question, but you combined them with a singleton, which is not needed at all. You said MainWindow has an instance of Worker, so just connect to a signal from the Worker. Since you didn't provide any code, I'll make something up.

```
void Worker::doSomething()
{
    ...

    // When we get a message from the server emit a signal
    emit messageReceived();
}

...

MyWindow::MyWindow()
{
    auto worker = new Worker();

    // Connect to the Worker's signal
    connect(worker, &Worker::messageReceived, this, &MyWindow::handleMessage);

    worker->start();
}

void MyWindow::handleMessage()
{
    // The MainWindow can now do something in response to the server message
}
```

Comment: How would you define the signal in Worker class. I got an error "no matching member function for call to 'connect'. My signal definitioin: `void message_received();`

Comment: There's nothing wrong with what you've got, other than you've spelled your signal differently than mine. `void messageReceived();` should work just fine.